# How to resolve "file:/product/config/" or " "classpath:/product/config/"" to an absolute path in Spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

An input string

"file:/test/abc.pdf"

"classpath:/res/abc.pdf"

How to resolve and get AbsolutePath for both this string?

Eg O/P :

C:/users/product/test/abc.pdf

C:/users/product/project1/src/main/res/abc.pdf

Comment: What's the use case?

Comment: It very well _may not be possible_. This sounds like an XY problem; please explain in detail what you're trying to get done (not just how you're trying to do it).

Comment: @SimonMartinelli The string are coming from configuration files, either as "file:" or "classpath:" .....I need to write a generic util to resolve both the possibility and send the actual file

Comment: classpath is easy but in your file example you get only a relative path how would you know the absolut path?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli That is what my issue is. Can't we get it at runtime?

Comment: How would you do that? Is the relative path relative to where the application runs?